# When is the progress toward the Research Assistant badge shown?

Tags: support, badges, badge-progress

Here on *Meta Stack Overflow*, when I look at the info page for a tag, I see the progress toward the Research Assistant badge.

[image: screenshot]

In other sites, I don't see it, even if I am a 20K user. For example, I don't see it on:

- [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/199/)
- [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/252/)

I do see it on the following sites, even if I am not a 10K user:

- [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/44/kiamlaluno)
- [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/1229/kiamlaluno)

When is the badge progress shown?

Comment: Weird, I see it on all sites even Beta and even where my rep is really low.

Comment: All in a sudden, I have the feeling the answer is really simple. I hope not. `:)`

Comment: Bah! I knew it! It is simply shown in those sites where you don't have it. I confused that badge with another one. I guess I should delete this question. It is not really helpful to anybody, is it?

Comment: Well, it's not trivial that it's not showing once you already got it, so add it as answer for the sake of other poor souls like us. ;)

Comment: Let's see if a developer comments saying the progress toward the badge should be seen in any case, and it was not shown because a bug. `:)`

Comment: You know any "Summon Dev" spell? I lost my scroll... :P

Comment: I see you're making fine progress towards the Japanese Erotica bage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was simpler than I thought: The badge progress is shown only on sites where the badge is not already assigned. The user's reputation, as well as the fact the user is a moderator, doesn't matter.

Comment: I seem to be blind - where can I find my badge progress?

Comment: @Spontifixus For this one in particular, go to any tag wiki and look in the right-hand column.

Comment: @MatthewRead Wow. An answer more than two years after my question ;)